# My app is not showing status bar in iPhone 6 and 6plus

Tags: ios, iphone

My app is not showing status bar only in iPhone6 and 6plus. When I enter the background and foreground it, the status bar seems to appear.What has to be done to get status bar when view appears? 
Here is my coding

AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];
}
```

And in viewcontroller.m

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];
    [self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
}
- (BOOL)preferedStatusBarHidden
{
    return NO;
}
```

and in Info.pList I set View controller-based status bar appearance to NO
and Status bar is initially hidden to NO

Comment: make sure you are not hided the status bar in UIApplication delegate methods.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `UIStatusBarHidden` with value `NO` in your `Info.plist`

Comment: How about setting it in your ViewController then?  

Try adding this method to your ViewController:

- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
{
    return NO;
}

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to know for sure without seeing your projects but there are four possible issues that come to mind.

Check the plist and make sure that: "View controller-based status bar appearance" is not set to "NO". If it is not listed (which is likely), this is fine too).

There is another plist settings which could cause this issue at loading only. Make sure that "Status bar is initially hidden" is set to "NO".

Third, ensure that "Hide during application launch" is unchecked on Targets -> General-> Hide status bar.

Finally, make sure that you do **not** have this code somewhere in viewDidLoad:

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
{
   return YES;
}
```

Comment: Still the issue exists but status bar appear in iPhone 4s and 5.

Comment: It's difficult to tell for me without seeing some code.

Comment: I have added the code. Please let me know where the issue occurs. And the project was created in previous version of Xcode 3.2

Comment: Try removing the 2 lines in your appDelegates as well as the 2 lines in your ViewWillAppear method of your VC, and add this to your view controller class:

-(UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle {
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}

Answer (score 0):

It is not an issue. It is a feature of IOS8 to hide status bar in landscape mode.